# A WHERE statement in my SqlDataSource causes invalid character exception (ORA-00911), why?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, where-clause, sqldatasource, selectcommand

I'm using Oracle developer tools and my generated `select` command is:

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT &quot;FIRSTNAME&quot; FROM &quot;USERS&quot; WHERE (&quot;USERNAME&quot; = ?)">`
```

Then I removed all `&quot;` and replaced them with a single quote: `'`.

Then I get that error (mentioned in the title).

Any suggestions how I can make it work?

Comment: Looks like stackoverflow replaced my marks with ". My original code included '&quot;' instead of ".

Comment: Did you search for escaping special characters in SQL

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. (I'm pretty noobie in asp.net)

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using like this

`select firstname from users where username='%?'`

Just replace the value in the where condition with your live values. Note down the syntax of SQL

Comment: Fine, basic SQL syntax is a bit common . if this worked, you can mark this as answer

Comment: Im sorry, but it doesnt work after all. However, the error message doesnt show up anymore, the return value is empty. So there must be something with the query, because the same query works and returns a value when Im doing it in SQLTools.

Comment: it means that your where clause has something wrong. post the sql query that you are generating now and we can figure out whats the problem

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="FirstNameSQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UserQueries.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT &quot;FIRSTNAME&quot; FROM &quot;USERS&quot; WHERE (&quot;USERNAME&quot; = '%?')">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="UsernameBox" Name="USERNAME" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: So Im getting my parameter from a textbox, but I tried with a default value as a parameter, the result says it is still empty (I used the count method on the sqldatasource to make sure it has a result at all or not)

Comment: you should be using like this `SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE UserName = ?` as given here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad%28v=vs.140%29.aspx or take a look at the sample here, though for a different one, but will be useful for you. http://forums.asp.net/t/1158209.aspx?oracle+SqlDataSource+parameter+mismatch

Comment: yep, I tried with SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE UserName = ?, but it shows an invalid character exception again. And when I write '%?' instead of ?, the error disappears, but the return value is again empty.

Comment: After all, the latest link you gave me had an awesome hint and it worked, thanks so much!